# How to maintain dimension of non-square image in a round image container

Tags: css

I am creating a round avatar in the user's profile and intend to set the user's image in the round avatar container.

If the image is a square there will not be an issue

[image]

However, I was not able to constraint an image which is not a square image for example for this non-square image

[image]

I will get this result

[image]

This is the CSS code I am using

```
.avatar_container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.avatar_container img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

What can I do to always maintain a round avatar? And that the image in it won't be distorted? overflow should be hidden

Comment: Have you tried defining a max height?

Comment: What is the desired result of the second image?

Answer (score 17):

UPDATE: @grenoult found a link with a great solution using css transforms. This is nicer than my previous solution because it allows you to crop tall and wide images. Check it out: http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/.

OLD ANSWER:
What you want to do is create a square container div and put the border-radius on that. Then, size the image to fit it.

HTML:

```
<div class="mask">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFao1.png" />
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.mask {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {max-width: 100%;}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V2Xjy/

Comment: How do you do when you images in landscape size too? http://jsfiddle.net/uk4p5h8m/

Comment: @grenoult I doubt there's a css-only solution to that. With JS you could detect if the image was portrait or landscape, then set either its max-width or max-height to 100%.

Comment: I actually find this that works for my case: http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/

Comment: @grenoult very nice! Including this in my answer.

Answer (score 12):

This post is a bit old but another option to achieve a circular image from a portrait or landscape image is to use object-fit (which is now supported, at least for img tags in all browsers but IE).

## HTML

```
<div class="mask">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFao1.png" />
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Dispite @alexvance already gave that useful link, I will add the entire code to ensure it will still remain after link becomes broken…

#### Example

[image]

#### HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="landscape-img.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="portrait-img.jpg" class="portrait" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.thumbnail img.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Kai Qing's suggestion to try max-height is helpful to include as well. This allows you to mask a 'source' image which isn't square without distortion.

http://jsfiddle.net/bw99N/2/

```
.mask {
    display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   max-height: 100px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```